# AWS ECS Fargate Container Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, terraform, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

Issue:

I am deploying ECS Fargate using Terraform. When I deploy everything goes great, but then the task fails saying "Essential container in task exited". I expanded the task and it says exit code 134. I have tried upping the CPU and Memory, and triple checking the files, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Anyone have any advice?

Files:

`fargate.tf`

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "backend_task" {
    family = "backend_example_app_family"

    // Fargate is a type of ECS that requires awsvpc network_mode
    requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
    network_mode = "awsvpc"

    // Valid sizes are shown here: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/
    memory = "1024"
    cpu = "512"

    // Fargate requires task definitions to have an execution role ARN to support ECR images
    execution_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn}"

    container_definitions = <<EOT
[
    {
        "name": "example_app_container",
        "image": "250531645249.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecr_example_repo:latest",
        "memory": 512,
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 3000,
                "hostPort": 3000
            }
        ]
    }
]
EOT
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "backend_cluster" {
    name = "backend_cluster_example_app"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "backend_service" {
    name = "backend_service"

    cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.backend_cluster.id}"
    task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.backend_task.arn}"

    launch_type = "FARGATE"
    desired_count = 1

    network_configuration {
        subnets = ["${aws_subnet.public_a.id}", "${aws_subnet.public_b.id}"]
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.security_group_example_app.id}"]
        assign_public_ip = true
    }
}
```

`iam.tf`

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_role" {
  name = "ecs_role_example_app"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_policy_attachment" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_role.name}"

  // This policy adds logging + ecr permissions
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

`network.tf`

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_example_app" {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    enable_dns_support = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_a" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc_example_app.id}"
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_b" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc_example_app.id}"
    cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc_example_app.id}"
}

resource "aws_route" "internet_access" {
    route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc_example_app.main_route_table_id}"
    destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group_example_app" {
    name = "security_group_example_app"
    description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic on port 80 (http)"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc_example_app.id}"

    ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 4000
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port = 0
        protocol = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably related to the container image.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking it might be because previously it was working just fine. Maybe I should run the image locally and make sure it is working

Comment: Are there no logs from the container that is exiting? Adding that container's logs to your question would be a minimum amount needed to help you. Also seeing the task definition, and possibly the Dockerfile used to create the image would be helpful as well. "Maybe I should run the image locally and make sure it is working" Yes please make some effort to debug this yourself before asking questions like this on here.

Comment: It's very hard to know as @MarkB says where it went south. I've also noticed that container and host ports are set to 3000, while in the SG you have set an entire range between 80 and 4000. That means **all** the ports between the two can be used.

Comment: I have made a great effort to debug, including trying to add logs, but it keeps failing. I have tried and failed, which is why I am asking here. The task definition is in the file above. I can add the docker file. I ran the image locally, and it's working fine.

Comment: @MarkoE That was really helpful, and I was able to fix it! I noticed I messed up the port and memory on the task definition. Once I fixed that, it worked! Thank you!